# What is the best way to reheat meat with fried rice?

Tags: reheating

How should i reheat my chicken with fried rice so the meat remains moist and the rice is not rubbery??

Comment: How are you reheating it now -- what have you tried that isn't working? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to reheat fried rice (or any steamed rice for that matter) is to microwave it.  The key is to microwave it sufficiently.  Try starting with 1:30 min per cup of rice, 3:00 min for 2 cups, etc.  No need to add water.  The resulting steam from the microwaved rice should be enough to keep the chicken moist.

Comment: I agree in principle, but it might depend on your microwave power. 90s for a cup of fatty fried rice in my microwave & I'd have bullet-holes in the ceiling ;) I exaggerate, but it would definitely be more 'done for' than 'done'.

Comment: @Tetsujin I guess some styles of fried rice are oilier than others.  The way I make it (Japanese/Hawaiian-style?) uses only the oil rendered from whatever meat I happened to be adding to it (if any), and actually it comes out rather fluffy.  Sorry, this turned off-topic.  Reconsidering the oil factor and also that some Asian rices are harder/drier (like Chinese rice), I would have to re-think the timing/water issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use a wide skillet with a small amount of water in it. Heat the water to boil, then distribute the fried rice. Cover and reduce heat to low. Wait five minutes. Stir or fluff the rice. Add the chicken (which I assume is in little bits). Cover. Turn off the heat. Wait an additional five minutes.

Should be nice!